# Sometimes I have a number, sometimes I have nothing. Is the `Number` type appropriate in the Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There's a field in my database where sometimes I want to store a number. However, sometimes I don't have a number to store (or I need to delete the number that was previously stored), so I want to store nothing (an empty field).

How should I store it? As `undefined`, as `null` or as `NaN`?

And is the `Number` type correct for my use? Or should I choose `Mixed`?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Number` as type and **not** set `required: true`. Or explicitly set it false. That will allow you to use both `null`, `undefined` and simply not having that field in the document.

Whether you want to store the undefined number as `null` or not having the field is up to you. You could also use both: don't have it defined in the document if it's not provided during creation, and using `null` when the number is not provided during update of the document, i.e. the number was removed at a later stage. That way you can tell if the number was there earlier if you ever encounter `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to understand now!